# Do kittens get balding in the area above their eyes?

Tags: cats, health, grooming

Why is it balding is it fungus like what my dog had
Not completely bald, but just thinner fur.

Comment: that part of the head has a lot of scent glands that the cat uses to mark you as his/her property.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on fur color and length, the area above the eyes might look thinner when observed from certain angles.

This is especially noticeable with black fur on the pink skin, since the individual hairs are not "flat" for the observer like the rest of the fur, instead they are oriented towards the observer.

Kind of like a dense forest observed from a distance compared to the same forest observed from a helicopter will look less dense.

With black fur, you will typically notice this effect starting from the eyes stretching all the way to the ears, as that is the area where the fur is somewhat thinner and the hairs tend to point in your direction when looking at them.

---

See the following picture taken from an angle where the effect is very pronounced for reference, this is our black cat and we've specifically asked our vet about this in the past and were assured it is perfectly normal.

[image: how it may looks like on a black cat from an angle where the effect is very pronounced]